# Is there a way to default Go's os package calls to run under a specific user

Tags: linux, go, mkdir

Basically I cant use `os.Mkdir` or `os.MkdirAll` because it will create the directories as root. I know I can go the `exec.Cmd` route and set the `syscall.Credential{}`.  But thats a bit cumbersome and I have to remove and replace a lot of code.

I was wondering if there was anything global I can set so calls to the os package will be ran as a specified user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run your application as the correct user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, a process will make system calls as the user that ran the process. Maybe `seteuid` is what you're looking for?